# How is the Eclipse sample project "Multipage Editor" supposed to run?

Tags: eclipse

I installed Eclipse Luna in XP yesterday and opened the sample project "Mutlipage Editor". When I click "Run" all that happens is another copy of Eclipse opens looking like the first copy but all the workspace boxes are empty.

I guess I was expecting either an emulator to start or the ability to run it on my Android phone. Can anyone get me started please?

Answer (score 0):

When you run an Eclipse plugin it has to run in an instance of Eclipse so that all the other plugins that the plugin depends on are available.

The default 'Multipage Editor' is associated with a file type (.mpe I think). So create a file with that type and open it to see the editor.

You can also write an Eclipse Rich Client Program (RCP) where you can select the available plugins and the look of the UI, but this requires additional code.

Comment: Thanks. OK let's take a step back, there's a much simpler "Hello World" example in the Tutorial - running that does the same thing (opens a new instance of Eclipse). It feels like something else should happen. Am I missing something?

Comment: Even the Hello World example requires other plugins and a complete Eclipse environment.

Comment: If you select 'would you like to create a 3.x rich client application' on the second page of the New Plugin wizard you will be offered some sample RCPs which don't launch the full Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry if I sound stupid but should the "Hello World" example display some kind of output? All I get is an empty copy of Eclipse. Do I need to click something in that new instance of Eclipse in order for something to happen?

Comment: All the examples which run in Eclipse will require you to do something to run the code. For Hello World you should get 'Sample Menu' in the menu bar, selecting 'Sample Action' in that menu runs the code.